# GPUImage : GPUImageVideoCamera with ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, gpuimage

I am trying to apply some filter on `GPUImageVideoCamera` and above the `GPUImageVideoCamera`, I am trying to add `ARKit`. But when `ARKit` session starts, GPUImageVideoCamera stop working, it seems to be a pause.

I have also try to keep `GPUImageVideoCamera` related part in my view controller A and I have presented view controller B with `ARKit`, then also it has the same issue.

Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit to share the same camera with a GPU video instance? probably better to make use of the ARKit session features, according to documentation "An ARSession object coordinates the major processes that ARKit performs on your behalf to create an augmented reality experience. These processes include reading data from the device's motion sensing hardware, controlling the device's built-in camera, and performing image analysis on captured camera images..."

What about using the "currentFrame" property instead?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure about the "currentFrame", but I have used "captureImage" in didUpdate delegate method and apply the filter. but this way it reduces the app performance.

Comment: Looking closer to your description "...when ARKit session starts, GPUImageVideoCamera stop working" I think you can first setup ARkit camera and the check if a camera is available using "AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession" if not then it will not be possible to create another instance for your GPUImageVideoCamera